# Jinja template not rendering inline style correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, static, jinja2

I have an Python string that looks like this:

```
patternBackground = 'background-color:#1CA2FF; background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml, ...
```

that I'm trying to render in a Jinja template as an inline html style:

```
style="{{patternBackground}}"
```

The problem is that the style gets cut off by it's first quotation mark so all that renders is..

```
background-color:#1CA2FF; background-image:url(
```

[image: Not rendering properly]

[image]

I've tried to escape the quotation marks in the Python string, this still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can encode this or pass the style string through as one whole thing (that isn't prematurely cut off)

Appreciate any help!

Isaac

Answer (score 1):

```
style="{{patternBackground|safe}}"
```